# Publish msi file within the artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I'm using the free artifactory version OSS and would like to deploy some msi that was built by jenkins.
So I'm using the artifactory plugin --> Generic Artifactory integration.
I created my own repository (lest call it MY_REPO) based on simple-layout.
In "Published Artifacts" jenkins field we provide the msi path.
So the question is:
how to deploy the msi in desired path : MY_REPO\component\ ver... 
I would like to use the current plugin and to pass the parameters but I don't see where it's done.

Thanks in advance,
Dima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the  **Published Artifacts** section

XXX/*.msi => com/aaa//1.0.$BUILD_NUMBER

where **XXX** is the path of your msi file , **com/aaa** is the relative path on your artifactory & **BUILD_NUMBER** is the current build number

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful.